# undefined value when calling server code from javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I'm calling a server method from javascript.  I've tested the server method and it works correctly.  when I call the server method from javascript i get an undefined value instead of true of false.  Can anyone tell me how to get the correct value?

this is the javascript method I am calling

```
function IsElectronic(programId) {
    var isElectronic = PageMethods.IsElectronic(programId);
    alert(isElectronic); //  The alert says undefined
    return isElectronic;
}
```

Server side call - this method works correctly

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool IsElectronic(long programId) {
    var taskProcessor = new TaskBL();
    var IsElectronic = taskProcessor.GetDelieveryType(programId).ContainsValue("ELECTRONIC");
    if (IsElectronic) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a webservice is an asynchronous operation. To get the result you have to use a callback.

```
function IsElectronic(programId) {
    PageMethods.IsElectronic(programId, function(result) {
        alert(result); // true
    });
    // you cannot return a value, there isn't one yet
    //return isElectronic;
}
```

Comment: @gilly3 LOL, I was surprised I made it :)

Comment: how do I pass the result value to the calling javascript function?

Comment: You can't pass it back, because that would have to be synchronous. The caller can provide a callback which you can execute though. Look at the PageMethods.IsElectronic method -- it doesn't return a value, but you can get the value from the callback. Same thing.